# Date Conversion in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, type-conversion

I have a query that generates this table:

| DateCompleted | GtrReference | SourceWarehouse | TargetWarehouse | DateCreated | EntryType | ControlAccount | InitialValue | Operator | FirstDesc | SecondDesc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202302 | 01062023 | W | 01 | 2023-01-06 00:00:00.000 | W | 1610 | 6080.00 | CWHITE | IN TRANSIT WAREHOUSE | MAIN WAREHOUSE |
| 202302 | 01172023 | W | 01 | 2023-01-17 00:00:00.000 | W | 1610 | 6210.00 | CWHITE | IN TRANSIT WAREHOUSE | MAIN WAREHOUSE |
| 202302 | 02022023 | W | 01 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00.000 | W | 1610 | 3616.00 | CWHITE | IN TRANSIT WAREHOUSE | MAIN WAREHOUSE |

The Query:

```
select
DateCompleted,
GtrReference,
SourceWarehouse,
TargetWarehouse,
DateCreated,
EntryType,
ControlAccount,
InitialValue,
Operator,
FirstDesc,
SecondDesc
from
(
    select
    concat(d.TransfCompYear, case when len(d.TransfCompPeriod) = 1 then '0' end, d.TransfCompPeriod) as DateCompleted,
    a.Complete,
    d.Line,
  d.TransfCompPeriod as DateMonth,
  d.TransfCompYear as DateYear,
  a.GtrReference as GtrReference,
  a.SourceWarehouse as SourceWarehouse, 
  max(a.TargetWarehouse) over (partition by a.GtrReference) as TargetWarehouse, 
  a.DateCreated as DateCreated,
  COALESCE(d.ExpectedDueDate, d.ExpectedDueDate) as ExpectedDueDate,
  a.EntryType as EntryType, 
  a.ControlAccount as ControlAccount, 
  max(a.InitialValue) over (partition by a.GtrReference) as InitialValue,
  a.Operator as Operator,
  b.Description as FirstDesc, 
  c.Description as SecondDesc
FROM 
    [GtrMaster] a  
    LEFT JOIN [InvWhControl] b  
     ON (a.SourceWarehouse = b.Warehouse) 
    LEFT JOIN [InvWhControl] c  
     ON (a.TargetWarehouse = c.Warehouse) 
    LEFT JOIN [GtrDetail] d  
     ON (a.GtrReference = d.GtrReference) 
) as i
    WHERE ( i.EntryType = 'W' OR i.EntryType = 'S' ) 
     AND i.Complete = 'Y' AND i.GtrReference >= '' 
     and i.Line = '1'
     and i.DateCompleted >= convert(varchar(6),getdate()-90,112)
    ORDER BY i.DateCompleted desc
```

What i'm trying to do is change the DateCompleted column to show an actual date.

Ex, I want to change 202302 to show 2023-02-01, and 202301 to show 2023-01-01. How can I convert my current date column to that?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: What's wrong with `CONVERT`/`CAST`?

Comment: @Larnu Cast as datetime gives me The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Cast as date gives me Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: `202302` is not a valid date it's just a number, so why is an error a surprise? You need to cast a *valid* date so you should concatenate the missing digits.

Comment: Store dates as dates. Avoid storing them as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Convert*:

```
Convert(DateTime, [DateCompleted] + '01') As TrueDateCompleted
```

The returned date values you can format as you like.

Answer (score 0):

A calendar table would be very useful here.

From a calendar table you could `CONCAT()` the year and month columns for each date (or use a YearMonthNum column). Then join this column to your DateCompleted column, returning only the first date of each month via some distinction clause e.g., `WHERE DayNum = 1`